# Android widget works only on emulator not on real device

Tags: java, android, widget, android-virtual-device

The widget is working perfectly on emulator 4.1.2, when installed on a real device it doesn't even show on the widget list, just as installed but I cant get it to work properly.

here's the manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.staccato.conectauaem"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name="WgtProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="WgtReceiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.staccato.intent.action.CONNECT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget" />
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and the widget provider

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
    android:minHeight="47dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="146dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="146dp"
    android:minWidth="47dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: What does "I cant get it to work properly" mean, exactly?

Comment: it doesn't show on the widget list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with hard reset, installed the widget and then restarted the device, then it showed up on the widget list.